# Missing Colon After Property ID, Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, html, firebase

I am writing a program that needs to read and write to Firebase, my server backend. I'm not sure why, but the JS interpreter says that I'm missing colons and my definitions are off. Here is the exact error:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id firebase.js:14:31
ReferenceError: refs is not defined visview.js:18:1
ReferenceError: addUser is not defined
```

However, I've clearly defined these things, and my functions are formatted correctly. Maybe I'm missing something.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Web of Hunger</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="visGraph" class="visNetwork">
      <canvas height="100%" width="100%" style="position: relative; -moz-user-select: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
    </div>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.12.0/vis.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.12.0/vis.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/visview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

firebase.js:

```
var refs = {
      root : new Firebase("Sorry, I am not allowed to show the URL"),
      users : new Firebase("Sorry, I am not allowed to show the URL"),
      graph : {
        graph : new Firebase("Sorry, I am not allowed to show the URL"),
        nodes : new Firebase("Sorry, I am not allowed to show the URL"),
        edges : new Firebase("Sorry, I am not allowed to show the URL")
      }
    };

    //data manipulation functions (low level to high)

    var addNode = function(node){
      refs.graph.nodes.update({node.name : "temp"});
      refs.graph.nodes.child(node.name).set({
        "id" : node.id,
        "label" : node.label
      });
    };

    var addEdge = function(edge) {
      refs.graph.edges.update({edge.name : "temp"});
      refs.graph.edges.child(edge.name).set({
        "from" : edge.from,
        "to" : edge.to,
        "arrows" : edge.arrows
      });
    };

    var addUser = function(name, edges)
    {
      if(refs.users.child(name) === null)
      {
        var time = Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;

        if(refs.graph.nodes.child(name) === null && refs.graph.edges.child(name) === null)
        {
          refs.users.update({name : {}});
          refs.users.child(name).update({
            "id" : time,
            "edges" : {}
          });
          refs.users.child(name).child("edges").update({
            "to" : {},
            "from" : {}
          });

          addNode(new Node(name, time, name));

          for(var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++)
          {
            var nme = edges[i].name;
            refs.users.child(name).child("edges/to").update({nme : true});
            addEdge(new Edge(name, time, edges[i].to, edges[i].arrows));
            //TODO add a "from" edge so that you know who wants to eat you
          }
        }
      } else {
        alert("Username, node name, or edge name taken.");
      }
    };
```

visview.js:

```
//handy data structures

var Node = function(name, id, label) {
  this.name = name;
  this.id = id;
  this.label = label;
};

var Edge = function(name, frm, to, arrows) {
  this.name = name;
  this.from = frm;
  this.to = to;
  this.arrows = arrows;
};

//functions that allow vis to read firebase data

refs.graph.graph.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());

  //main vis update section
  getGraphDataAsVis(snapshot.val());

});

var getGraphDataAsVis = function(data) {
  //var nodes = refs.graph.child("nodes").
};
```

app.js:

```
addUser("tester1", [new Edge("test1", 0, 1, 'to')]);
addNode(new Node("tester2", 400, "tester2"));
```

Comment: The syntax error is almost certainly causing the other errors. Because that code in "firebase.js" cannot be parsed, it won't be executed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax error:

```
  refs.graph.nodes.update({node.name : "temp"});
```

In modern (ES2015) JavaScript, that would be

```
  refs.graph.nodes.update({ [node.name] : "temp"});
```

In older versions of JavaScript, there's no compact way of doing it. You could write a helper function:

```
  function obj() {
    var rv = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
      rv[arguments[i]] = rv[arguments[i+1]];
    return rv;
  }
```

Then:

```
  refs.graph.nodes.update(obj(node.name, "temp"));
```

The helper function "obj" just treats its arguments as a sequence of name-value pairs of values. The first argument is the first property name, the second is the first property value, and so on. Prior to ES2015, the language did not support the concept of evaluating an expression on the *left* side of a `:` in an object initializer in order to determine a property name. Only property values could be expressions evaluated as part of the interpretation of the object initializer; property names had to be constants.

Comment: This is my first time using old JS since like a year ago. I've recently been in love with Babel, a JS compiler that turns ES6 to ES5 and below.

Comment: Well sure, if you're using Babel then that would do the trick. However even ES2015 would give you that syntax error because you left off the `[ ]`.